# Org-mode - TODO item shown ONLY in Agenda for day/week

Tags: emacs, org-mode

is there any way in Org-mode to mark some TODOs in a way that they are shown only when their time comes and start showing only in agenda day/week until they are marked as done?

Comment: How are you determining "when their time comes"?  Using SCHEDULED:, DEADLINE:, a timestamp for the desired time?  By only in Agenda day/week view, do you mean as opposed to within a block agenda/list of todo items?

Comment: Yes, only SCHEDULED: and DEADLINE:.

Answer (score 5):

The Org-Mode Manual section on [Deadlines and scheduling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-scheduling) shows that you can set item-specific lead-times on the warnings for `SCHEDULED:` and `DEADLINE:`.  Lead-time is how many days before the date it will appear in your Agenda to warn you of the upcoming task.

Setting your timestamp to `<Scheduled Date -0d>` or `<Deadline Date -0d>` will set the warning lead-time to 0 days.  This ensures that it will not show up until the day the timestamp indicates.  Overdue items will continue to appear until marked done.

Two things to note:

1. This will not hide the TODO item from the Agenda TODO list obtained used `C-c a t` (List of all TODO entries).
2. If you complete a task before the `SCHEDULED:` date (For example you complete it on [2011-11-22] and it is `SCHEDULED:` for [2011-11-25]), it will still show up on the `SCHEDULED:` date if `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` is set to `nil`.  To prevent this behaviour you have to set the following:

   ```
   (setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
   ```

Comment: Yes I would really like them out. The best would be for the scheduled tasks to appear just after the date they were scheduled to occurs.

Comment: Setting your timestamp as <Scheduled Date -0d> means it will appear on the day it is scheduled, and in the future.  It will not appear before that day.  `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` only relates to scheduled tasks that are completed before their scheduled date (if you complete on the 22nd and it's scheduled the 23rd for example it will still show up as done on the 23rd, if the variable is set to nil).